# Activity's onDestroy is called instead of onResume when bringing the app to foreground from recent list

Tags: android, android-activity, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a singletop activity.
When i push it to background onPause() gets called.
When i bring the app back from recent apps, on Resume gets called.
Everything works fine.
but in API level 10 devices, (2.3.6)
when i bring the activity to foreground from recent list 
    onDestroy() is called. 
    onResume(),finish() nothing is called.
    onDestroy() is called straightaway.

In what scenario could this be happening?
I thought device is running low on memory, but that is no the case.

Comment: Sounds like your app is crashing. Do you see any errors in logcat? Perhaps you are using an Android API that is not supported in API level 10?

Comment: Its working fine for all devices above API 10

Comment: No the app is not crashing, the previous activity which is singleInstance is called.

Comment: I'm not using any API that is not supported in level 10.
Also, this bg is not reproduced if i change the launchMode to standard or singleInstance.
But i cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be happening on any device as it does not contradict to Activity lifecycle. Therefore, you can not do anything to address that specifically. Instead, I would initialize everything properly in `onCreate` and start/stop whatever needed `onResume/onPause`.

Comment: Thnx! butSaving data is not a problem.
Its a file reader activity, and you would want your acitvity to retain its state when you pull it back from background.

Comment: You could use Activity's onSaveInstanceState putting all the important data into the bundle. Then in onCreate you get the data back from the savedState bundle. In onSaveInstanceState call super.onSaveInstanceState() last, so the bundle goes where it should go.

Comment: Again i'll say saving data is not a problem.
i want my activity to be resumed.
The activity is actually a file-reader activity.
And when i push it to background and pull the app back from recent apps, i'll want the file to be open, not the activity to be destroyed. After which the main activty is shown currently, as its before this activity in stack.

Comment: Let your activity reopen the file in onCreate if it decides from the saved state that such a file was opened before the activity was destroyed. You can save current position in file, too.

Comment: Thnx!Yes i can do that, restart my activity.
But what i dont understand that why is my activity being destroyed.And only on API level 10 phones and only in the case of singleTOp activity.

Comment: It is safe to say it gets destroyed for no reason, same consequences.